# how to redirect blogger internal page to blogger home page

Tags: redirect, blogger, blogspot

I want to redirect a blogspot internal page to home page of same blogger. how i can do this. 
for example i want to redirect internal page :
`http://unblockedaddictingames.blogspot.com/2016/01/unblocked-addicting-games_12.html`
to Home page of same blogspot :
`http://unblockedaddictingames.blogspot.com/`
Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

Redirection can be done with javascript.

Add the following code at the top of the blog post you want to redirect (make sure to edit it in the HTML mode):

```
<script>
  window.location.href = "http://unblockedaddictingames.blogspot.com/";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the default feature of blogger.

Log-in into blogger and go to `Settings > Search Preferences` and set the `Custom Redirects`. You also have option to choose Permanent or Temporary redirection.

Reference: [Blogger Help](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/41373?hl=en&rd=1)